# Differential equations with Mathematica

Tags: equations, mathematica

How can I input this differential equation in Mathematica and see the solving steps?

[image]

Comment: If we assume that the solution is equally valid using *Mathematica* and Wolfram Alpha, I see no reason to close this question. There must be some sensible threshold before the knee-jerk close question reaction just because a webapp was mentioned.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I figured Mathematica was part of Wolfram Alpha. As apparently it's not, is just a bad question for any Q&A site, it being too broad? Still then, migrating is *not* closing, but a way to help folks getting better answers.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be here, but http://math.stackexchange.com *might* be better. Wolfram Alpha has *notoriously* poor input functionality.

Comment: If you want to ask about web apps, try http://nothingtoinstall.com/ otherwise, leave just the non-webapps portion

Comment: y= -x is a trivial solution

Answer (score 4):

In Mathematica, you need to put it in the following form:

```
eqn = x*y'[x] - y[x] == Sqrt[1 + x^2]*y'[x] + Sqrt[1 + y[x]^2]
DSolve[eqn, y[x], x]
```

With that I get:

> {{y[x] -> 
>      InverseFunction[1/2 (ArcSinh[#1] + #1 (-#1 + Sqrt[1 + #1^2])) &][
>       1/2 (-x (x + Sqrt[1 + x^2]) - ArcSinh[x]) + C[1]]}}

with the following warning:

> Solve::tdep: The equations appear to involve the variables to be solved for in an essentially non-algebraic way.

From the help it appears that the solver encountered a transcendental function. That's about as far as I can take this. Hope this helps get you going.